# How can I make syntax highlighting files more readable and maintainable?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Vim uses regular expressions for syntax highlighting. Often maintaining these can become rather unwieldy. For example:

```
syn match goVarAssign /\v[_.[:alnum:]]+(,\s*[_.[:alnum:]]+)*\ze(\s*([-^+|^\/%&]|\*|\<\<|\>\>|\&\^)?\=[^=])/
```

For example Python supports [comments inside regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X), which would make things a lot more helpful:

```
syn match goVarAssign /\v
    [_.[:alnum:]]+          " One or more valid identifier characters.
    (,\s*[_.[:alnum:]]+)*   " Repeated one or more times separated by ,
    \ze                     " Start matching here
    (
      \s*                   " Any whitespace
      (                     " ... um?
        [-^+|^\/%&]|
        \*|
        \<\<|
        \>\>|
        \&\^
      )
      ?\=[^=]               " .. um?
    )
/
```

The above pseudo-example does not work, but is there any way to approach something like that in Vim?

Comment: Maybe an option would be to build the command in a string variable (it is then possible to comment each part of the string) and then use `execute()` on the built string? That's clearly not as good as python but I'm not sure there are better option.